# Data.Map vs. Data.Array for symmetric matrices?

Tags: arrays, haskell, dictionary

Sorry for the vague question, but I hope for an experienced Haskeller this is a no-brainer.

I have to represent and manipulate symmetric matrices, so there are basically three different choices for the data type:

1. Complete matrix storing both the `(i,j)` and `(j,i)` element, although `m(i,j) = m(j,i)`

   Data.Array (Int, Int) Int
2. A map, storing only elements `(i,j)` with `i <= j` (upper triangular matrix)

   Data.Map (Int, Int) Int
3. A vector indexed by `k`, storing the upper triangular matrix given some vector order `f(i,j) = k`

   Data.Array Int Int

Many operations are going to be necessary on the matrices, updating a single element, querying for rows and columns etc. However, they will mainly act as containers, no linear algebra operations (inversion, det, etc) will be required.

Which one of the options would be the fastest one in general if the dimensionality of the matrices is going to be at around `20x20`?  When I understand correctly, every update (with `(//)` in the case of array) requires full copies, so going from `20x20=400` elements to `20*21/2 = 210` elements in the cases 2. or 3. would make a lot of sense, but access is slower for case 2. and 3. needs conversion at some point.

Are there any guidelines?

Btw: The 3rd option is not a really good one, as computing `f^-1` requires square roots.

Comment: If the matrix size is small like 20×20, you do not need square roots for 3.  You can at least use a table lookup, although there may be a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using Data.Array using a specialized Ix class that only generates the upper half of the matrix:

```
newtype Symmetric = Symmetric { pair :: (Int, Int) } deriving (Ord, Eq)

instance Ix Symmetric where
    range ((Symmetric (x1,y1)), (Symmetric (x2,y2))) =
        map Symmetric [(x,y) | x <- range (x1,x2), y <- range (y1,y2), x >= y]
    inRange (lo,hi) i = x <= hix && x >= lox && y <= hiy && y >= loy && x >= y
        where
          (lox,loy) = pair lo
          (hix,hiy) = pair hi
          (x,y) = pair i
    index (lo,hi) i
        | inRange (lo,hi) i  = (x-loy)+(sum$take(y-loy)[hix-lox, hix-lox-1..])
        | otherwise = error "Error in array index"
        where
          (lox,loy) = pair lo
          (hix,hiy) = pair hi
          (x,y) = pair i

sym x y 
    | x < y = Symmetric (y,x)
    | otherwise = Symmetric (x,y)



*Main Data.Ix> let a = listArray (sym 0 0, sym 6 6) [0..]
*Main Data.Ix> a ! sym 3 2
14
*Main Data.Ix> a ! sym 2 3
14
*Main Data.Ix> a ! sym 2 2
13
*Main Data.Ix> length $ elems a
28
*Main Data.Ix> let b = listArray (sym 0 0, sym 19 19) [0..]
*Main Data.Ix> length $ elems b
210
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a fourth option: use an array of decreasingly-large arrays. I would go with either option 1 (using a full array and just storing every element twice) or this last one. If you intend to be updating a lot of elements, I strongly recommend using a mutable array; IOArray and STArray are popular choices.

Unless this is for homework or something, you should also take a peek at Hackage. A quick look suggests the problem of manipulating matrices has been solved several times already.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to IOArray/STArray. I'm in the midst of learning Haskell, so I prefer to come up with my own solutions to get familiar with the language, even if this means less-than optimal solutions.